# First Letter uppercase

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript in ASP.NET, I need to convert lowercase letters into uppercase letters.

How can I solve this problem with correct answer in JavaScript?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>

<script language="JAVASCRIPT">
     function capitalizeMe(obj) {
         val = obj.value;
            newVal = '';
         val = val.split(' ');
         for (var c = 0; c < val.length; c++) {
             newVal += val[c].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
             val[c].substring(1, val[c].length) + ' ';
         }   
     }
</script>

</head>
<body>
     <form id="Form2" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur="capitalizeMe(this)">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please search on SO before posting: dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script language="JAVASCRIPT">
 function capitalizeMe(obj) {
    val = obj.value;
        newVal = '';
     val = val.split(' ');
     for (var c = 0; c < val.length; c++) {
    newVal += val[c].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
 val[c].substring(1, val[c].length) + ' ';
  }
    obj.value = newVal;
   }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you use css instead?

```
.capitalized{
    text-transform: capitalize
}
```

Add the class to your elements and have css handle the rest

Comment: I love this CSS approach.